# React - populating <li> error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am implement some basic navigation in React, I have the following code:

**EDITED .js**

```
 var Navigation = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      navigationItems: [
        { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Home', 'url': '/home' },
        { 'id': 2, 'name': 'About', 'url': '/about' },
        { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Contact', 'url': '/contact' }
      ]
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <ul>
          {this.props.navigationItems.map(function() {
            return (
              <li><a href={this.props.url}>{this.props.name}</a></li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Navigation
```

It's throwing me the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`. Any ideas why?

Comment: pass `this` in as the second argument in map, after the function.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have it in a different component that passed it to `Navigation`, `navigationItems` is not a prop. You should access it normally by calling `navigationItems.map()`

Comment: How do I loop through the `navigationItems` array, so that it populates 3x the `<li>`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're setting any props. Instead of a variable assignment, use [getDefaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values) to load up an initial object for your props:

```
var Navigation = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      navigationItems: [
        { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Home', 'url': '/home' },
        { 'id': 2, 'name': 'About', 'url': '/about' },
        { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Contact', 'url': '/contact' }
      ]
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>...</ul>` part should be

```
<ul>
  {this.props.navigationItems.map(function(item) {
    return (
      <li key={item.id}><a href={item.url}>{item.name}</a></li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

`this.props.navigationItems` is an array. When it gets iterated on by using `map`, you could access each item of the array in the callback. Check [the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Also, remember to set a key on each list item tag for React to perform better.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for-loop would suffice I think? [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/zcy4f4Lz/).

```
var Navigation = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      navigationItems: [
        { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Home', 'url': '/home' },
        { 'id': 2, 'name': 'About', 'url': '/about' },
        { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Contact', 'url': '/contact' }
      ]
    };
  },
  render: function() {
      var navItems = [];
      var length = this.props.navigationItems.length;
      var id = null;
      var url = null;
      var name = null;
      for(var i=0; i<length; i+=1) {
        id = this.props.navigationItems[i].id;
        url = this.props.navigationItems[i].url;
        name = this.props.navigationItems[i].name;
        navItems[i] = <li key={id}><a href={url}>{name}</a></li>;
      }
      return (
        <nav>
          <ul>
            {navItems}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      );
  }
});
React.render(<Navigation />, document.getElementById('container'));
```